# Trouble performing a MongoDB aggregation query to match objectId in a nested array

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I am facing an issue with a MongoDB aggregation query that aims to find arts based on a given "type" and "version" of an offer, where the offerId exists in the "linkedOffers.include" array.
Here are examples of how my offer and art documents look like:

Offer document:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "6452110c0881247e0a8d17d2" },
  "type": "TYPE_1",
  "version": "VERSION_1"
}
```

Art document:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "6571bcbd9be813d7440e8055" },
  "artName": "Art 0",
  "linkedOffers": [
    {
      "offerType": "TYPE_1",
      "include": [
        { "offerId": { "$oid": "6452110c0881247e0a8d17d2" } }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have attempted the following aggregation query:

```
offers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      type: "TYPE_1",
      version: "VERSION_1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "arts",
      let: { offerId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$$offerId", "$linkedOffers.include.offerId""
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "linkedArts"
    }
  }
])
```

However, this query does not return any matched arts, even though it should.
When I tested the `$match` stage separately, it worked fine for an individual art document.

I suspect the issue is with the match expression "$linkedOffers.include.offerId", as linkedOffers.include is an array of objects.
I have also checked that matching arts directly with linkedOffers.include.offerId works using a separate query.

Can someone help me understand why the `$match` stage in the aggregation pipeline is not working correctly and provide a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

In the mongo query language, an equality match of a single item against an array will return true if the array contains that value.

This means you can use the correlated form of lookup, and avoid the $expr expression that sometimes confounds index usage.

```
db.offers.aggregate([
 {$match: {
      type: "TYPE_1",
      version: "VERSION_1"
 }},
 {$lookup: {
      from: "arts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "linkedOffers.include.offerId",
      as: "linkedArts"
 }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IwKWKYX2pPU)

Comment: Hey @Joe thanks for your response!
I'm familiar with this option, and it works for me.
But, I don't want to use it, I want to use the pipeline because I have 2 conditions for the match, the first one is the objectId (as you did here), and the second one is "linkedOffers.offerType" = "TYPE_1", and the relationship between them should be OR.
I didn't write it in the question because I wanted to focus on the first condition because the second one works fine to me.

Comment: Ah, in that case, take a look at this playground to see what "$linkedOffers.include.offerId" actually contains at that point: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9RZU7nsDVt6
You will likely need to use $reduce with $concatArrays to flatten that to a simple array to use with $in.

Comment: thanks for your helpful response!
Would you recommend to organize the data in a different way so the query will be simpler?

Comment: That is always a possibility, but really depends on why the data is structured this way, and what other types of queries need to be considered.  On possibility would be to add an array to each art document to hold the _id of the offers linked to it.  With a simple array on one side or the other the lookup is simpler